# URL's are repeated

Tags: go, hugo

I want to output my breadcrumbs using schema, but the `@id` repeats the URL twice or sometimes more than that?! So if I visit the `about` page, I see:

`"@id":"http://localhost:1313/about/http://localhost:1313/about/",`

When I use pagination, it repeats the URL even more:

`"@id":"http://localhost:1313/blog/http://localhost:1313/blog//http://localhost:1313/blog/http://localhost:1313/blog//http://localhost:1313/blog/http://localhost:1313/blog/",`

**The code I am using:** 
Taken from: https://gohugohq.com/partials/breadcrumb-partial-with-structured-data-in-hugo/

```
{{ $url := replace .Permalink ( printf "%s" .Site.BaseURL) "" }}
{{ $.Scratch.Add "path" .Site.BaseURL }}

{{ $.Scratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" .Site.BaseURL "name" "home" "position" 1 )) }}
{{ range $index, $element := split $url "/" }}
{{ $.Scratch.Add "path" $element }}
{{ $.Scratch.Add "path" "/" }}
{{ if ne $element "" }}
{{ $.Scratch.Add "breadcrumb" (slice (dict "url" ($.Scratch.Get "path") "name" . "position" (add $index 2))) }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{{ range $.Scratch.Get "breadcrumb" }}{{ if ne .position 1 }},{{ end }}{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": {{ .position }},
        "item": {
          "@id": "{{ .url }}",
          "name": "{{ .name }}"
        }
    }{{ end }}]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, there will always be a trailing comma in your `itemListElement` logic. Only show the comma if it's not first _and_ not last.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure what your list page template looks like, but for example in mine I had

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}
```

when it should have been

```
{{ partial "header" . }}
```

This removed the repeating url's. I have all of the same code you have rendering in my header partial.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons URLs are repeated

1. Its known bug with hugo hot reloading. But final production version will not have it. So run `hugo` and check the public folder.
2. If the issue persists on public folder then check how many partials you are doing `{{ $.Scratch.Add "path" .Site.BaseURL }}`. After you add it once then same data is available via scratch on all partials of the same page.

I have blog post on [breadcrumb partial for hugo with json-ld](https://apoorv.blog/breadcrumb-json-ld-hugo/)

I reuse the same scratch to display breadcrumbs on page.

DONT JUST ADD BREADCRUMBS FOR SEARCH ENGINE. SHOW THEM TO USERS ALSO.